# How to search for text in a MongoDB collection based on data stored in another collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

Say we have 2 collections in a Mongo Atlas database.

- Users
- Inventory

`Users` has `name` and `userId`

`Inventory` has `inventoryId`, `userId`

I want to search for all the inventory items by name of the user. There can be multiple entries in the user table with the same name. What is an efficient way to do this, which can also handle a lot of documents in these 2 collections?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to *search* a lot of documents, in two collections, where text is one of the filter criteria (in this case `name`), the best solution is often lookup.

Here is an example modified from the sample_mflix dataset on the steps you would need to cover in your aggregation pipeline:

```js
 var db = Products,
      joinSearchQuery = db.Users.aggregate([
        {
          '$search': {
            'text': {
              'query': 'Ned Stark', // could also be autocomplete to be a nicer feature
              'path': 'name'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$lookup': {
            'from': 'Inventory', 
            'localField': 'userId', 
            'foreignField': 'userId', 
            'as': 'inventoryFromUser', 
            'pipeline': [
              ...
            ]
          }
        }
      ]);
```

What's interesting about this query is that the name search aspect could be really expensive and crappy if just a regular text query, as searches are best done using Atlas Search. If there is an interactive search form, autocomplete using `$search` could also be interesting. There's a free forever tier so it doesn't cost money unless it's very big.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. This seems very promising.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know the most efficient way is to use $lookup, but it is only available in a stage of an aggregation pipeline

```
mongo.collection('users').aggregate([
    ...
    {$lookup: {
        from: "inventory",        //name of the collection           
        localField: "userId",     //localField
        foreignField: "userId",   //foreignField
        as: "inventory".          //as <=> name in the document
    }},
    ...
]).toArray(),
```

This kind of doing usually require data manipulation because the new field added is an array.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot. would you happen to know about the performance implications of this?

Comment: From the (way too) numerous tests I've been doing with mongo aggregations you have to be very careful about the number of documents you allow to pass each stage. Moreover not that $skip, $limit and $sample are not panaceas as you can see from my last question (every document needs to be scanned). The best thing to do is to have a $match on index field as the first stage to limit the number of document to be scanned by mongo. IMPORTANT: indexes are useless to an aggregation for anything that is not the first stage ! You can use .explain("executionStats") to find the indexes used by mongo. GLHF!